# Does a widcard cert invalidate existing subdomain certs?

Tags: ssl-certificate

I have several certs from godaddy for subdomains like vpn.mysite.com and data-server.mysite.com. If I purchase a wildcard cert for *.mysite.com will my current certs become invalid and need replacing? Or can I use them til they expire then swap them out for the wildcard?

Comment: A certificate is only invalidated when it expires, or if the authority that created it puts it on a revoke list. The revoke list is in my experience not used very often since it then relies on the client actually checking if a certificate has been revoked or not. Either way, you should ask godaddy, if they are the ones who issues the certificate.

Comment: I did and it was the most frustrating fifteen minutes of my life trying to get an understandable answer out of their support agent.

Comment: Why does it matter? Just replace them with your wildcard cert.